# Unbound : what capacity will i need on drive?

Tags: unbound

I'm planning to set up my own dns server (for a cybercafe, 30 computers)

what size will unbound need on hdd after months of use ?

Mb, Gb, Tb ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `unbound` does not store much on disk (unless you turn up the logging). The cache is held in memory. If you really want to there are commands for dumping/restoring the cache from disk. (This is discouraged as it allows you to load old data into the cache)

I have a server that's handled 44m queries since last restart and dumping the cache to disk takes 13MB. It really doesn't need much space, although you may as well make sure you have a few GB of RAM so the cache can comfortably fit alongside the rest of the system with room to spare.

Note also that while you say "after a month of use", a resolver's cache doesn't really grow that much over time. It acts kind of like a library; It'll immediately fill up with all the books everyone wants, but then stay fairly consistent. The odd new or obscure book may get added if people request it, but old disused books are being removed at the same time. (Yes incoming comments, this isn't exactly a perfect analogy but you get the idea)

Answer (score 1):

As @@USD Matt wrote, it does not use much space, besides it almost doesn't grow in size. AFAIR we have it something like 128m, so...